# Real life example of List,Tuple,Set and Map

Tags: scala

I can use Array to make the List of the Songs.Because Array supports Random Access.i.e I can play the songs in different index in the same time.In the same way I need the real life examples of List,Tuple,Set and Map.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a List to store the steps necessary to cook a chicken, because Lists support sequential access and you can access the steps in order.

You can use a Tuple to store the latitude and longitude of your home, because a tuple always has a predefined number of elements (in this specific example, two). The same Tuple type can be used to store the coordinates of other locations.

You can use a Set to store passport numbers, because a Set enforces uniqueness among its elements. Passport numbers are always unique and two people can't have the same one.

You can use a Map to convert a list of Imperial/US measurements to their Metric (SI) equivalents because a Map takes a list and applies an operation to each member of the list and returns a new list (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function) )

Comment: I thought the OP wanted an example of `Map`, not `map`, but then again, clarity doesn't appear to have a been a priority.